# How to add an interceptor to one specfic url in springboot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, interceptor

I have a UserController class as below:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
    @Resource
    UserService userService;

    @PostMapping("/create")
    public Map<String, Object> createAccount(User user) {
        return userService.createAccount(user);
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public Map<String, Object> accountLogin(User user) {
        return userService.accountLogin(user);
    }

    @GetMapping("/activate")
    public Map<String, Object> activateAccount(String confirmationCode) {
        return userService.activateAccount(confirmationCode);
    }

    @PostMapping("/roleChange")
    public Map<String, Object> setUserRole(String uuid, String email, String roleId){
        return userService.setUserRole(uuid, email, roleId);
    }
}
```

Now I wanna add an interceptor to `/user/roleChange` only. I know you can exclude all the other paths with `.excludePathPatterns()` but I'm just curious if there's a way to specify one path for the interceptor. Thank you!

Comment: Now if only there also was an [`addPathPatterns`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/InterceptorRegistration.html#addPathPatterns-java.lang.String...-) which would specify the patterns that should match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the sample code for interceptor

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new CustomInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/user");
    }
}

public class CustomInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello..");
        return true;
    }
}
```

In this I have register "/user" for interceptor.

> registry.addInterceptor(new CustomInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/user");